# If WCF is the future why do searches for "web services" still point to ASMX?

Tags: wcf, web-services, asmx, popularity

I am needing to create a web service, so the first thing I did of course was go to [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=making+a+webservice+in+C%23&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a)

If you look in those results, you'll see nothing but things about ASMX, which apparently is dubbed legacy technology to be replaced by WCF. Why is it that ASMX is still so vastly popular compared to WCF? (of course, on SO WCF is way more popular.. hmmm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's older and more established. Therefore there are more pages on the Interwebs referring to it.

It also uses different terminology (because WCF is more than just web services) so you're not going to see it show up in Google as often for a search on "Web Services".

Answer (score 0):

It used to be the case that if you searched on MSDN for "web service security", you'd find articles on WSE. That doesn't mean that WSE is not obsolete, and that nobody should use it  unless they have no choices.

It just means that poor suckers who don't check the dates on articles and don't do good research from search results wind up creating new projects using WSE. I see it several times a month.

Search engines are quite as capable of returning you excellent results for five years ago as they are of returning excellent results for today.

Answer (score 0):

Because WCF is referred to as such on the web, seeing as it is not *just* web services. Note the second letter in the TLA. :)